# Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation for pass the data to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I got this error for passing data to PHP file using jQuery.

> Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation.

Can some one tell me how to resolve this? Thanks.

This is my code:

```
function updatetask() {

    var tid = document.getElementById('task_id').value;
    var pid = document.getElementById('projct_id').value;
    var title = document.getElementById('ts_title').value;
    var desc = document.getElementById('description').value;
    var tag = document.getElementById('tag').value;
    var sdate = document.getElementById('sdate').value;
    var edate = document.getElementById('edate').value;
    var status = document.getElementById('status_option').value;
    var complete = document.getElementById('ts_complete').value;     
    var uid = document.getElementById('assign_id').value;   

    $.ajax({  
        type: 'POST',  
        url: '<?php echo $url; ?>/js-files/updateTitle.php', 
        data: { task_id: tid, proj_id: pid, task: title, descrip: desc, tags: tag, start: sdate, due: edate, state: status, complete: completed, emp_id: uid },
        success: function(data) {
            alert('success update assign');  
        }
    });

}
```

javascript console return this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
add
buildParams 
buildParams 
buildParams 
jQuery.param 
jQuery.extend.ajax
updatetask
onclick
```

Comment: Throw us a bone, eh? Which line is giving that error message?  Is it coming from the JavaScript, PHP or web browser?

Comment: What does "<?php echo $url; ?>" show?  Also, can you post a little bit of what updateTitle.php has?

Comment: updateTitle.php is data update file. it separate to jquery code.

Comment: to Jeremy -> it's coming from javaScript code $.ajax({ line